# C# System.Timers.Timer auto-shutdown?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, timer

I have a Timer which kicks off and does it's job indefinitely in it's own thread until something happens in the main thread to disable it, in which case a different one will be enabled. This works perfectly. The only problem is that I want to make COMPLETELY sure the second timer doesn't run for too long.

Is there a way to make a timer automatically disable after, say, 10 minutes if it doesn't receive a specific shutdown command due to some malfunction?

I see that the class has a [InitializeLifetimeService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) method. It sounds like it could help but I have no idea how to work it.

Thanks guys and gals :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider starting a third Timer when you start the second one to disable it after a given time.

```
        Timer t1 = new Timer(1000); // fire every second
        Timer t2 = new Timer(60000); // fire after 10 minutes
        t2.Elapsed += (o, e) => t1.Stop(); // disable timer 1 when timer 2 is elapsed

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
```

The example above makes use of **System.Timers.Timer** by the way. If you are using **System.Threading.Timer** you might consider a switch there as well for surprisingly enough **System.Timers.Timer** is the one who is threadsafe by nature, where **System.Threading.Timer** is not.

Quite good overview can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

**EDIT for clarity:**
the line

```
t2.Elapsed += (e, o) => t1.Stop();
```

could also be written as

```
 t2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(t2_Elapsed);
```

followed by

```
void t2_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    t1.Stop();
}
```

which is what you actually get when hitting Ctrl+Space in Visual Studio, given hat you have access to t1 in the lower method.

Comment: Can you chew out the syntax in line 3? I am not sure I understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you make it put a +1 to a global variable every iteration (say if it ticks every second), make the timer check the variable every tick and once the var reaches 600, tell the timer to disable itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a Class variable and set it when you start the timer to DateTime.Now. Then include this in your timer:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, time.AddMinutes(10)) > 0)
       {
           timer1.Stop();
       }

       // timer code
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign an elapsed event handler and global Boolean

```
     Private Boolean eOccured = False;

     System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
     aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
     aTimer.Interval = 600000; //milliseconds(10 min)
     aTimer.Enabled = True;
```

...
Code activates bool if successful
...

Then stop the timer on event trigger.

```
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        If (eOccured)
        {
            aTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
```